# Passing JSON through AJAX Plus Button Dilema

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, button, alert

so I am attempting to pass some information in a JSON object and have a php page insert the data into a database. However, I am running into some trouble. The "update" button exists in a popup window. The user then clicks "update" and the inputted data should be processed accordingly. However, I fear that I am not even reaching my .click function. None of my alerts seems to be triggered. Below I will point out where issues are occurring. Thank you!

```
    <script>
    function updateTable()
    {
        document.getElementById("testLand").innerHTML = "Post Json";
        //echo new table values for ID = x
    }
    $('#update').click( function() {
        alert("help!");
        var popupObj = {};
        popupObj["Verified_By"] = $('#popupVBy').val();
        popupObj["Date_Verified"] = $('#popupDV').val();
        popupObj["Comments"] = $('#popupC').val();
        popupObj["Notes"] = $('#popupN').val();
        var popupString = JSON.stringify(popupObj);
        alert(popupString);
        #.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "popupAjax.php",
            //data: 'popUpString = '+ popupString,
            data: popupObj,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                updateTable();
                alert("testing tests");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

<html>
<button onClick="openPopup(<?php echo $row['ID'];?>);"><?php echo $row['ID'];?></button> <!--opens a popup with input options-->
<button id="update">Update</button> <!-- this button is supposed to cause the javascript above to run when clicked, however none of my alerts seem to be reached.-->

</html>
```

Thank you for looking!

Comment: See the code working here: http://jsbin.com/zocekohalo/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)I can only guess that you're trying to use JQUERY?
Where do you include the library?

2 )#.ajax isnt valid Jquery function

try $.ajax instead

Comment: Thanks for the response Artur, that did not seem to change anything. Since I am not seeing the initial alert("help!") I feel like the function is not even being run.

Comment: <script src="js/jquery-ui/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> is in the head of my php page

Comment: Can you see any errors in console? 
Can you see '$' is undefined? IS the Jquery included in your HTML (view source and find it)

Comment: Wrap you script in $(document).ready(function(){ //yourjs code }), refresh the page and click the <button id="update">Update</button> . You should see the error in error console (you can open the console by pressing F12 and clicking the 'console' tab in most browsers)

Comment: it says I have an error on my last )); that should be a }); I believe, I am retesting now.

Comment: Is it possible that the target is still focused on the popup Window that was closed and not the main panel.

Comment: Can you update the code in your main question please?
When you click the #update button does the console stay empty?

Comment: I performed the code update. I get this error when i click update.         GET SITE_ROOTscripts%5Cjquery-ui-1.10.4.custom%5Cjsjquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 44ms]

Comment: I'd recommedn to fix the front-end issue first and then add the PHP part. The error you're getting now is a 404 for jquery.ui. Please note: jquery.ui is not the same as jquery